# Is it known what would have happened in later seasons of "Everything sucks!"?

Tags: everything-sucks

[*Everything Sucks!*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7078710/), a 2018 Netflix comedy show, got renewed then cancelled after its first season, presumably due to low retention and audience.

However, some "future seasons" elements had obviously been planned ([it's even confirmed by the creators](https://www.tvguide.com/news/everything-sucks-lukes-dad-kate-coming-out/)), notably through

> Oliver's departure, Kate and Emaline's relationship, and Luke's father coming back.

For instance, when [*Revolution*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2070791/) got cancelled, the crew patched up a comic which tied up loose ends from season 2. My Googling doesn't bring such a thing for *Everything Sucks!* (nor plans on it), but I thought **maybe the showrunners later revealed what they had in mind, in an interview perhaps?**

Or, if it's "too soon" for that to be released, is there any indication the writers still consider renewing it?

Comment: We can't answer "what would have happened" because it didin't happen, and if they decided to continue the series writers could change the script. It's too speculative.

Comment: @Luciano I'm not asking for speculation here, rather whether there is a "word of god" answer on what was planned (like it was done for other series). That doesn't seem POB.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is going to be a definitive "this is what was planned", as there have been a couple of post interviews and commentaries from the authors without any revelation. One of the more telling that I found was a commentary from Michael Mohan (One of the co-creators) on a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/EverythingSucks/comments/8q663s/everything_sucks/):

> So when the show was not renewed, I think for a lot of us who hadn't seen ourselves represented onscreen, it felt downright personal. Because Kate Messner will always be in the closet. And we'll never know what Luke and Sherry would have done with Leroy knocking at their door. And I'm sure you'll always wonder what happened to Oliver in NYC. (Personally speaking, I was pretty devastated to not be able to tell Emaline's S2 arc, as that was the character I related to the most.)

From all indications, he *knows* at least some of what was planned for season 2, and chose not to tell it. It may also be because they evidently sold the rights to it to Netflix, who are unwilling to sell it back. If I didn't own the rights to a show, I wouldn't reveal my plans as a writer either. So the bottom line is they probably know, but they aren't telling.